# Search output of AWK in another file

Tags: command-line, text-processing, awk

I have two files fileA and fileB.

I have to extract column1 from fileA like `awk '{print $1}'` and then the output will be searched into other fileB and will save the matched records into a new file fileC in simple words like:

`fileA`:

```
seg1     rec1
seg2     rec2
seg3     rec3
```

I need to retrieve column 1 by using awk command and this column 1 is searched into `fileB` to retrieve the records like:

`fileB`:

```
seg1     one
seg2     two
seg3     three
seg4     four
seg5     five
```

From fileA, column1 data is extracted and
and this data is used to search in fileB and matched record is saved to a test file.
My output should be like this:

`fileC`:

```
seg1       one
seg2       two
seg3       three
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Can be achieved easily with `awk` as follows:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{inFileA[$1]; next} ($1 in inFileA)' fileA fileB > write_to_fileC
```

result,

```
seg1       one
seg2       two
seg3       three
```

at above, first we are reading the *fileA* and holds the entire column1 from into an array named *inFileA*, then look in fileB for its first column and if it's matched with the saved column1 from fileA then goes to print entire row of fileB.

Answer (score 4):

If the columns to be compared are sorted, you can use `join`:

```
join -o 2.1,2.2 file1 file2
```

`join` matches sorted columns from input files and prints them. `-o 2,1,2.2` restricts the output to first and second columns of the second input file.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following one-liner:

```
cut -f1 fileA | grep -f - fileB > fileC
```

- the `cut` command will extract the first column of `fileA` (assuming tab separation. use `-d` to specify something else)
- the `grep` command takes the output of `cut` and searches `fileB` for all strings.
- the output will be written to `fileC`

Comment: Note that this assumes the fields are tab-separated.

Comment: @terdon yes, I know. I mentioned this in the first bullet point ;-)

Comment: Argh. So you did. Sorry!

Answer (score 2):

An attempt with bash script. (Remember to make executable.)

`fileA` and `fileB` should exist in the same folder as the script.

A general script which will work for any two files described with script and generate the file with matching text as  `<fa>_<fb>_match.txt`:

To use this, run `./script_name.sh fileA fileB`

```bash
#!/bin/bash
fa="$1"  # first file- which has  columns
fb="$2"  # second file - which has  raw data to be searched
# file with name <fa>_<fb>_match.txt will be generated.

myarr=($(awk 'NR>1 {print $1}' "$fa")) # NR makes awk to ignore first row.

for index in ${!myarr[@]}; do
    #echo $index/${#myarr[@]}
    #echo    "${myarr[index]}"
text="${myarr[index]}"
grep -w -F "$text" $fb  >>  $fa"_"$fb"_match".txt
done

# file with name <fa>_<fb>_match.txt will be generated.
```

Comment: This will also match substrings. For example, if `fileA` contains `fooseg1` and `file2` contains `seg1`, it will be considered a match.

Comment: You could fix that with grep's `-w` option. You could also do the whole thing in one step, there's no need for the array: `awk 'NR>1 {print $1}' "$fa" | while read index; do ...`. Oh, and you should always [quote your variables](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/22222). That said, using the shell for this sort of thing is really [not a good idea](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716/22222). It is hard to write, easy to get wrong and will always be very slow.

Comment: I am relatively new to shell scripting, and as mentioned by the links, I will study and improve my style. Thanks for the links. Really helpful !

Comment: You're very welcome. We're all here to learn!

Answer (score 2):

You have already received some excellent answers. Just to add to the mix, here's a Perl approach:

```
$ perl -ane '$i ? $k{$F[0]} && print : { $k{$F[0]}++ }; $i++ if eof' fileA fileB
seg1     one
seg2     two
seg3     three
```

And a golfed version of [αғsнιη's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/862296/85695):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR ? a[$1] : $1 in a' fileA fileB 
seg1     one
seg2     two
seg3     three
```

And here's a kinda convoluted `grep` solution:

```
$ grep -Ff <(grep -oP '^\S+' fileA) fileB
seg1     one
seg2     two
seg3     three
```